# How can I make something like fire which is safe?

Tags: home-experiment

I want to know a magic trick that helps me put  my hand on fire without burning. My teacher told me you can use acetone but I should fire it fast in my hand because of [volatility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_%28chemistry%29). Also I want to have fire that doesn't get put out fast; can I fire acetone for 5 minutes?!

If I fire acetone in my hand it may burn my hand. Are there any safe materials for my experiment?
Is there anyway to convert this heat into cold or Protectival material from burning?

I am looking for cold fire(fake fire)!

I read an article about [cool flame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_flame);can I use it for solving my problem?

Comment: Of course there's always the heat when you say "fire". I wonder though if there are chemicals that produce something visually similar to fire, which would ideally be what you're looking for.

Comment: Of course, you can use _lycopodium powder_.